# Problema al verificar que mi usuario esta en la base de datos ORACLE

Tags: php, sql, oracle, pdo

¿Existe algún tipo de conflicto con rowCount? La sentencia entiendo que esta bien, y estoy utilizando PDO, que tampoco me dio problemas anteriormente

El campo en la base de datos es VARCHAR2.

Adjunto mi código:

```
    $user = 'pepito'
    $con = connection();
    $statement = $con->prepare("SELECT name FROM usuarios WHERE name = :usu");
    $statement->bindParam(':usu', $user);
    $statement->execute();
    //Con este contador, devielve 1 si encuentra el usuario
    $contador = $statement->rowCount();
```

El contador me devuelve 0, cuando tendría que devolverme 1.

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que el registro tiene el campo exacto "pepito" y no uno con espacios en blanco antes o después? Ten en cuenta que en oracle [las comparaciones de los campos `VARCHAR2` son "nonpadded"](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements002.htm). ¿Si haces un `SELECT name FROM usuarios` te funciona y muestra el número de registros de la tabla?

Comment: @OscarGarcia si, el campo en la bbdd no tiene espacios ni antes ni despues, y al ejecutar la sentencia en el SQL Developer si me devuelve registro. He probado a cambiar el código, utilizando PDO query, pero no me devuelve nada...

Comment: ¿Probaste lo que te dije? ¿Probaste únicamente `SELECT name FROM usuarios`?

Comment: @OscarGarcia acabo de probarlo, sigue dando 0... No entiendo nada

Comment: AHHHHHHHHH, ¡espera! Ya sé dónde está el problema ^_^ ¡`rowCount` devuelve el número de registros afectados por el último `DELETE`, `INSERT` o `UPDATE` y no el número de registros devueltos por una consulta! Eso puede confundir y no funciona siempre si se usa para ese propósito.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una llamada a `rowCount()` tras una consulta `SELECT` puede devolver 0 en vez del número de registros obtenidos dependiendo de la base de datos.

Tal y como puede leerse en la [documentación oficial de `PDOStatement::rowCount()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.rowcount):

> `PDOStatement::rowCount()` devuelve el número de filas afectadas por la última sentencia `DELETE`, `INSERT`, o `UPDATE` ejecutada por el correspondiente objeto `PDOStatement`.
>
> Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto `PDOStatement` asociado fue una sentencia `SELECT`, **algunas bases de datos podrían devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia**. Sin embargo, **este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos** y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables.

Por lo que no debes confiar en ella para conocer el número de registros obtenidos, debes para eso hacer uso de la consulta SQL `COUNT` o bien de obtener todos los registros con [`PDOStatement::fetchAll()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetchall) y hacer un [`count()`](http://php.net/count) al resultado obtenido.

Comment: Dios, en efecto, no había caído en eso. Muchísimas gracias Oscar.

Comment: De nada. Si es para comprobar si un usuario existe o no en la base de datos basta con que hagas un [`PDOStatement::fetch()`](http://php.net/pdostatement.fetch) y si devuelve `false` es porque no hay registros devueltos y si es diferente entonces sí los hay :)